# The verb "fix" versus "set" in proofs

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

When would the word "fix" be more appropriate than the word "set"?

For instance, for this proof to show that if $T(cx+y) = cT(x) + T(y)$, then $T$ is linear, I'd like to begin by stating "Fix c to be 1." Would fix be the right word, or would set be better?

Thanks!

Comment: "Set" would be better. The meaning of "fix" in mathematics is complicated to spell out in detail because it often begins an implicit use of universal generalization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization).

Comment: "Let" would be better.

Comment: "Set" is as good as "fix".

Comment: Both is not correct, because we cannot assume that $c=1$. I would write "This holds for all $c\in F$. In particular, for $c=1$, we obtain $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$."